# Making an assignment in a has_many relationship is making an update in the DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to use a somewhat complex grouping and Rails is making it very hard for me.

I have a `FundsDestination` model which has a `has_many` relationship with `ProjectFundsDetail`. This one has `belongs_to` relationships with `Project` and `Subsection` and an `amount` attribute. When I'm creating my `FundsDestination`, the idea is that I input the full amount for each Subsection, and I select many projects, and when I save it, it should distribute those amounts among each Project, creating a `ProjectFundsDetail` for each project and subsection. In the View, I'm actually making one PFD for each Subsection, and distributing the amounts on the `create` action. This is working fine already.

But then I have to edit that `FundsDestination`. If I just load the `FundsDestination`, it will show a PFD for each PFD, but remember I only want to show one PFD for each Subsection, so I have to group them. In order to do that, I came up with this:

```rb
def edit
  @funds_destination = FundsDestination.find(params[:id])

  Subsection.enabled.each do |subsection|
    amount = @funds_destination
             .project_funds_details.readonly!
             .select { |pfd| pfd.subsection == subsection }
             .sum(&:funds_amount)
    @funds_destination.project_funds_details.build(subsection: subsection, funds_amount: amount)
  end
  @funds_destination.project_funds_details = @funds_destination.project_funds_details[-3..-1]  # line 49
end
```

This actually works fine too in the edit, and it works fine when I save it. But then I tried to cancel instead of saving, and I found out that (in the FundsDestination index) the FD that I was editing now didn't have any PFD. I checked on the DB and the PFD had the `funds_destination_id` set to `null`. When I check the server log, I see this is happening when I enter to edit:

```
    Started GET "/funds_resolutions/1/funds_destinations/2/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-11-25 03:33:22 -0300
    Processing by FundsDestinationsController#edit as HTML
      Parameters: {"funds_resolution_id"=>"1", "id"=>"2"}
      [...] blah blah [...]
       (0.2ms)  BEGIN
      ↳ app/controllers/funds_destinations_controller.rb:49
      ProjectFundsDetail Update All (9.8ms)  UPDATE `project_funds_details` SET `project_funds_details`.`funds_destination_id` = NULL WHERE `project_funds_details`.`funds_destination_id` = 2 AND `project_funds_details`.`id` IN (562, 563, 564, 565, 566, 567, 568, 569, 570, 571, 572, 573, 574, 575, 576, 577, 578, 579, 580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 586, 587, 588, 589, 590, 591, 592, 593, 594, 595, 596, 597, 598, 599, 600, 601, 602, 603, 604, 605, 606, 607, 608, 609, 610, 611, 612, 613, 614, 615, 616, 617, 618, 619, 620, 621, 622, 623, 624, 625, 626, 627, 628, 629, 630)
      ↳ app/controllers/funds_destinations_controller.rb:49
       (49.3ms)  COMMIT
      ↳ app/controllers/funds_destinations_controller.rb:49
      Rendering funds_destinations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
    Completed 200 OK in 502ms (Views: 302.9ms | ActiveRecord: 64.8ms)
```

In line 49 (marked in the first code block with a comment) it's running an UPDATE query. It looks like as I'm assigning a different array of PFDs, then Rails decides that it has to apply that, even when I'm not using `save()`.

How can I avoid that UPDATE? Any idea will be very useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to assign the `@funds_destination.project_funds_details[-3..-1]` in a separate instance variable and use that variable in the form. Hope it helps!

Comment: @Emu hmmm I could try something like that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Better solution will be, when you click on the cancel button, capture the event and redirect to index action. I think problem will be on form routing. Correct me if i was wrong.

Comment: I mentioned the cancel button, but it has the same behaviour if you just go back or click any link of the sidebar

Comment: in line #47 you are buildinga PFD for each subsection then why are you assigning all the PFD's with @funds_destination.project_funds_details[-3..-1] in #line 49. Since you are assigning the has many colletion it will have call to DB and save the data which you have passed in #line 49.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that I should do it in another variable like Emu said. But even tho, there is no way to make a local assignation that doesn't impact on the DB?

Comment: instead of assigning you can use build in line 49. @funds_destination.build_project_funds_details = @funds_destination.project_funds_details[-3..-1]

Comment: But build will add PFDs. I want to show only the last 3

Comment: Remove #line 49 and loop in UI using below code @funds_destination.project_funds_details[-3..-1].each...

Comment: Oh. I didn't think about that, I feel so dumb. Thanks